# Is there any way to populate transient field from spring JPA specification

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have entity with a @Transient field and I am using JPA specification to filter data. I want execute a sub query and assign result to transient field form specification.

@Transient
private Integer delayedDays;

Comment: @Transient
   private Integer delayedDays;

Answer (score 0):

Using @PostLoad and @PrePersist annotations
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa

https://github.com/aballaci/springboot-jpa-sakila/blob/master/src/main/java/de/ballaci/jpa/domain/Film.java

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not useful